# Create a Supersedes Condition in Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework

As the title of the question states... I've got a database that is using a supersedes model to store information... meaning that each time a customer is edited, instead of updating the row, the software simply slams a new record into the database, and then updates the old records to have a pointer to this new record.

I was trying to draw the 1 <> 1 relationship, but am not sure exactly how to effectively draw this... any tips would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the off-topic comment, but this seems like an interesting model, do you have a link where I can read more about it? Google do not seem to helpful when googling "supercedes model".

Comment: I do not.  I'm supporting another package, and this was their design.  I'm only working within their parameters.  I would think that if you picked up a good book on db administration, that you could gain the info from that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal 1:1 relationship with the FK pointing to a new record on each update (which is actually an insert and an update). You just need to make sure you insert first and then update the FK reference to the newly inserted record.

Aside, if you do wish to keep old records you should move them to a different table instead of bloating the existing one considering those records are probably obsolete and will rarely need to be accessed other than for auditing.

Comment: I made the mistake... the relationship is actually going to be a 1:N relationship, because all the old records are being updated with the new ID.  I'm going to be experimenting later today with it, but I should be good to go.  I've got to stop working late ni...err...early mornings on projects and get some sleep ;)